# BIOS cannot find any disks and will not proceed past the startup screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, boot, bios

I should start this question out by acknowledging the numerous poor choices that led to this situation.

For some time now I have been thinking about switching from Windows to Linux as my primary operating system, after using the former for most of my life, aside from occasional dalliances with dual booting Ubuntu or using a MacBook at my job.

I decided one day that I was going to finally make the switch, but retain Windows 10 on a separate partition in case I wanted/needed to go back. I downloaded Ubuntu 17.10 and created a live USB, then set to installing it. There was a stumble where I assumed that Windows had installed in UEFI mode (it was actually in BIOS mode, and thus Ubuntu would not work as I had installed it in UEFI mode), but once I resolved that I had a working dual-boot system set up that could boot into Windows *or* Ubuntu via grub. The partition setup on my SSD was roughly like this:

```
----------------------------------
Windows Reserved (100MB)
----------------------------------


Windows 10 Partition (190GB)


----------------------------------
Windows Recovery Partition (500MB)
----------------------------------

Ubuntu Partition (60GB)

----------------------------------
```

Let's call them sdd0 through sdd3, in order. I installed grub to sdd3, on the Ubuntu partition.

Edit: the OS disk (sdd) has a MBR partition table, not GPT. Both Windows and Ubuntu were set up to boot in BIOS mode.

After this everything seemed to be okay. However, eventually (around late November) Windows wanted to install updates. Most upgrades installed successfully but there were two that always failed; one was KB4055254, but I don't remember what the other was. This caused my computer to try to install these missing upgrades each night, but each night they would fail (and of course, now you cannot disable updates even temporarily for Windows 10). I got very annoyed at my computer rebooting and failing to install these upgrades, so I decided to remove Ubuntu temporarily as I assumed that the upgrade issue was related to the fact that the MBR had been overwritten by grub.

My next course of action was to try to fix the MBR from Windows. I tried a couple different commands (which I cannot remember other than that the program used was bootsect.exe) but kept getting errors like "volume could not be locked" and "access denied". I believed that this was due to Ubuntu controlling the section of the drive that Windows was trying to write to. I decided then to delete my Ubuntu partition and try and fix the MBR from my initial Ubuntu live USB, or at least create a separate live CD/live USB using a different program that could fix the MBR.

I deleted my Ubuntu partition using Windows Disk Management and rebooted into my Ubuntu live USB. However, before going any further I decided better safe than sorry (ha), and began copying the contents of my Windows partition to another 4TB drive used file storage (NTFS formatted). Everything went smoothly until it came time to copy my Users folder from the Windows install (I was copying each top level directory separately). This copy operation was taking quite a long time and it was getting late, so I decided to leave it overnight.

In the morning I sat back down at my computer expecting the file copy operation to be finished so I could get back to trying to fix the MBR. It looked like the copy of Ubuntu running off the live USB had been suspended; it was not at the login screen, but the screen that comes before that... I guess you'd call it the lock screen.

I hit enter to go to the login screen, which it did, but at that point the UI froze. I could not enter the user password, and it did not seem to be responding to keyboard or mouse input. This is where I made the crucial and absolutely stupid mistake of hitting the power button, thinking I could just reboot into the live USB and continue on. The computer started booting up, and the BIOS screen came up (I have an ASUS p8Z68-V/GEN3 motherboard):

[image]

I heard the POST beep, and then it very quickly flashed this message:

[image]

And then went back to the BIOS startup screen. I was expecting it to then go to a black screen with a flashing cursor, like what usually happens when there is no bootloader on the active disk. However, what happened instead is that it just stayed on this BIOS startup screen, and refused to accept keyboard input.

It was at this point that I knew I was in very deep trouble. For some reason I cannot even enter the BIOS configuration. I've tried hitting F2, F6, F8, F12, Del, Esc, and Ctrl-Alt-Del. The only thing I can do is press Ctrl-Alt-Del to restart the BIOS sequence *before* the BIOS startup screen appears for the second time. If I wait until it gets to the startup screen for the second time and "freezes", Ctrl-Alt-Del will not cause a restart. Furthermore, I have tried plugging my Ubuntu live USB in, as well as a Windows 10 live USB, putting a Windows 7 recovery disk in the CD drive, and a Windows XP disk. The BIOS would not recognize or boot from any of these.

Other things I have tried to try to get past this second BIOS screen, with no success:

- Unplugging all peripherals except video output
- Unplugging my SSD
- Resetting the CMOS by moving the jumper to the rightmost two pins on the group of three that are labelled "reset" on my motherboard, waiting 10 seconds, and then moving it back.

The only thing I haven't tried is removing the CMOS battery, waiting for a minute, and then replacing it, because it is sitting under my graphics card.

What else can I do to try to get my computer to boot into either a live USB or installation CD? Why is my BIOS getting "stuck" during the startup sequence?

Comment: Your attempting to load a MBR boot disk while in UEFI mode. MBR wasn’t overwritten by GRUB2, MBR isn’t a boot loader, it’s a partition scheme.  GRIB is a boot loader, simulator to that of the Windows boot loader, you overwrote the Windows boot loader with Grub.  Boot into UEFI installation disk, while in UEFI mode, delete all partitions then install Ubuntu.

Comment: Windows XP doesn’t support UEFI, neither does Windows 7 other than the 64-bit Version.  Your first screenshot clearly shows the system in UEFI mode.

Comment: If that's the case, then why didn't the system boot from the Windows 10 USB? Surely that could boot in UEFI mode.

Comment: You can boot to the WinPE regardless what mode the system is in, but if you a HDR with MBR partitions, you won't be able to install Windows booted to that environment with EFI mode enabled.  The opposite is true, you won't be able to install Windows on a GPT disk, if EFI mode was not enabled.  My comment is limited to versions of Windows that even supports UEFI obviously.

Comment: Let me back up for a second then and reiterate that the system will not boot WinPE from USB, nor an Ubuntu liveUSB. Actually, it's not so much that it won't boot from them, as it is that it doesn't seem to see them.

Comment: That typically happens when you have created a WinPE disk that can only be used in one mode or another (although WinPE has no such restrictions by itself).  Tell us something about the disk your attempting to boot to.  EFI requires FAT32.

Comment: The Ubuntu live USB stick is formatted as FAT32. I also added additional information to my question specifying that the disk is using an MBR partition table.

Comment: This message can be normal if the disk is attached to the chipset and not to the JMicron controller. I would guess that a power glitch at night corrupted the BIOS, but unfortunately the Asus [BIOS update utility](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68VGEN3/HelpDesk_Download/) only runs from Windows. If going to a repair-shop to reinstall the BIOS is not an option, you may try on another computer to create a boot USB for reinstalling the BIOS.

Comment: For creating a DOS boot USB for reinstalling the BIOS, see [guide1](https://www.howtogeek.com/136987/how-to-create-a-bootable-dos-usb-drive/) or [guide2](https://www.geforce.com/whats-new/guides/how-to-update-your-motherboard-bios-using-a-simple-usb-stick).

Comment: How does this factor in considering that I can't seem to boot from USB? I've tried both a Windows 10 USB as well as a Ubuntu live USB and my system would not boot into either.

Comment: Have you tried F11 for the boot menu? If you can't boot USB at all, this is another problem with the USB on this BIOS, maybe 32/64-bit or legacy/UEFI,  which you can't verify because you can't get into BIOS setup. You might opt instead for a boot CD - you could get a portable drive if you don't have any on the computer. If the BIOS won't also boot from CD, a good repair-shop is the last choice.

Comment: I have; I've tried everything I could think of to get into the firmware settings, and also tried removing the CMOS battery. However, I am still unable to boot from USB, CD or disk, so I will likely replace my motherboard and call this one a write-off.

Comment: I think that the current motherboard can still be fixed - I believe the problem is with the BIOS and not with the hardware. I would also advise you to run from now on behind a power surge protector.

Answer (score 1):

First comment : No Linux live CD/USB can correctly backup Windows files,
because the two permissions models are completely different.

Second comment : The message of "No drives" can be normal if the disk is
attached to the chipset rather than to the JMicron controller,
but this does not seem to apply to your case.

I would guess that what happened is that a power glitch at night corrupted
the BIOS and you need to repair it.

Unfortunately the
[Asus BIOS update utility](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68VGEN3/HelpDesk_Download/)
only runs from Windows.
You could convert the utility to a boot CD or USB,
as explained
[here](https://www.howtogeek.com/136987/how-to-create-a-bootable-dos-usb-drive/)
or
[here](https://www.geforce.com/whats-new/guides/how-to-update-your-motherboard-bios-using-a-simple-usb-stick),
but you report that boot from USB does not work either
(and you haven't tried a CD or don't have a CD drive).

In short, your situation seems hopeless and your options seem to be only two:

1. A professional repair-shop might have the tools to reset the BIOS
2. You have communicated to us your decision to replace the motherboard.

In the future I would advise you to use a power surge protector
to avoid the problem happening again (although your case seems to
be rather rare and the result of really bad luck).

Comment: I may try creating a boot CD before installing my new motherboard, but I am skeptical of it working. I might also just take it to a repair shop and see what they can do. Out of curiosity, what kind of tools are needed to reset the BIOS, or is that the aforementioned bootable BIOS update CD?

Comment: The above-linked Asus BIOS update utility is enough by itself, but unfortunately it needs an operating system, as Asus didn't supply a complete boot CD/USB. I posted links on how to create a boot DOS environment to which you can copy this BIOS utility (and hope that DOS is sufficient for it to do the job). A good repair-shop might have a more professional software that can write this BIOS onto the motherboard.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't mention this before, but I _am_ using a UPS with a surge protector. I believe it was the OS installation itself that corrupted the BIOS, as I've heard there were problems with this version of Ubuntu (but curiously, only on certain laptops). Regardless, I've rectified the problem.